# unable to call a REST webservice..Full authentication required

Tags: spring, rest

I am currently working on spring application and REST webservices.
I have created a REST webservice in one application and want to access that service from other applications.
Below is the error its showing when trying to access the webservice.

```
RestClientException : org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

Below is my webservice code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = MyRequestMapping.GET_ACC_DATA, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public MyResponseDTO getSigDataValues(@PathVariable final String acc, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
       MyResponseDTO  responseDTO = null;
       try {
             //logic goes here
             //responseDTO  = ..
        } catch (Exception e) {
             LOG.error("Exception" + e);
        }
        return responseDTO;
    }
```

I am calling above webservice from another application.In the below mentioned method I am calling the webservice and its throwing me the exception `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException`.

```
public MyResponseDTO getAccData(String acc){
       try{
           list= (List<String>)restTemplate.postForObject(MyDataURL.GET_ACC_DATA.value(), MyResponseDTO.class, acc);
        }
        catch (final RestClientException e)
        {
            LOG.info("RestClientException :" + e);
        }
```

Please suggest, what am I missing.

Comment: 401 mean unauthorized request, ask the service provider which method authenticates the service.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to authenticate against the REST service. One of the most common ways is Basic Authentication. If this is what the service is using you would need to create an AUTHORIZATION header with Base 64 encoded usernamen + password.

RestTemplate allow to set customer headers before the request gets sent.

Comment: where to set the headers? I have create a controller class and written the webservice getSigDataValues(..) method as shown in my post.

Comment: In your RestTemplate

Answer (score 0):

The process of creating the Authorization header is relatively straightforward for Basic Authentication, so it can pretty much be done manually with a few lines of code:

```
private HttpHeaders createHeaders(String username, String password) {
    return new HttpHeaders() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1704024310885506847L;
        {
            String auth = username + ":" + password;
            byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
            String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
            set("Authorization", authHeader);
        }
    };
}
```

Then, sending a request becomes just as simple:

```
ResponseEntity<Dados> response = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET,
            new HttpEntity<Dados>(createHeaders(usuario, senha)), Dados.class);
```